# count * with where clause using JPA criteria query

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to find records for related_elements table, where relationId belongs to a list

suppose a Set tempSet contains[2,3,4]
I have to check for these value contains in related_element table using jpa criteria query

```
CriteriaBuilder cb1=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<RelatedElements> cq1=cb1.createQuery(RelatedElements.class);
        Root<RelatedElements> RelatedElementsRoot=cq1.from(RelatedElements.class);
    for (Integer tSet : tempSet) {
            ParameterExpression<Integer> pRelatedElement=cb1.parameter(Integer.class);
            cq1.multiselect(cb1.count(RelatedElementsRoot.<RelatedElements>get("relatedElementsPk").<Integer>get("relationId"))).where(cb1.equal(RelatedElementsRoot.get("relationId"), pRelatedElement));
            TypedQuery<RelatedElements> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq1);
            qry.setParameter(pRelatedElement, tSet);
            count = entityManager.createQuery(cq1).getSingleResult().getRelationId();
        }
```

but its now working...any suggessions

second try

```
CriteriaBuilder cb1=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Integer> cq1 = cb1.createQuery(Integer.class);
        Root<RelatedElements> RelatedElementsRoot=cq1.from(RelatedElements.class);
        for (Integer tSet : tempSet) {
            ParameterExpression<Integer> pRelatedElement=cb1.parameter(Integer.class);
            cq1.multiselect(cb1.count(cq1.from(RelatedElements.class)));
            cq1.where((cb1.equal(RelatedElementsRoot.get("relatedElementsPk").get("relationId"), pRelatedElement)));
            TypedQuery<Integer> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq1);
            qry.setParameter(pRelatedElement, tSet);
            count =qry.getSingleResult();
        }
```

its giving exception at qry.setParameter

> Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [java.lang.Integer] [select new java.lang.Integer(count(*)) from com.mcd.webex.model.RelatedElements as generatedAlias0, com.mcd.webex.model.RelatedElements as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias0.relatedElementsPk.relationId=:param0]

Comment: Could you show your cq1 string data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#count%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29), CriteriaBuilder.count returns `Expression<java.lang.Long>`. Consequently type argument to `CriteriaQuery` and `TypedQuery` should be Long as well. Same holds true for type of `count` variable.

When there is only one value to be selected, then it makes sense to use [CriteriaQuery.select](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#select%28javax.persistence.criteria.Selection%29) instead of [multiselect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect%28javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...%29), because then such an error is catched already in compile time.

```
Long count;
...
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq1 = cb1.createQuery(Long.class);
...
cq1.select(cb1.count(cq1.from(RelatedElements.class)));
...
TypedQuery<Long> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq1);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Dzialy> root = cq.from(Dzialy.class);
EntityType <Dzialy> Dzialy_ = root.getModel();

cq.select((cb.countDistinct(root)));
cq.where( cb.equal( root.get(Dzialy_.getSingularAttribute("DZI_id")), 1) ); 

long l = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

em - EntityManager
DZI_id - column name
1 - searching value
Dzialy - entity class

Comment: Thank you! I found that `cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(Entity.class)));` doesn't work correctly when a "where" restriction is introduced. But your method works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(YourEntity.class)));
cq.where(/*your stuff*/);
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.